# Manual calculation of ordinal logistic regression probabilities - starting at different comparison

Tags: regression, ordered-logit

I am having a little issue with manually calculating some predicted probabilities from a ordinal logistic regression (I am doing this as a learning exercise - I am aware I don't have to do this manually).
Take the following example from the UCLA statistics training website:

Import the data:

```
library(foreign)
library(MASS)
dat <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/ologit.dta")
```

Run an ordinal logistic regression:

```
m <- polr(apply ~ public + pared, data = dat, Hess=TRUE)
```

Get the predicted probabilities:

```
newdat <- expand.grid(public=unique(dat$public),pared=unique(dat$pared))
cbind(newdat,predict(m,newdat,type="probs"))

#  public pared  unlikely somewhat likely very likely
#1      0     0 0.5960409       0.3255546  0.07840448 # reproduce this row of results
#2      1     0 0.5720066       0.3421339  0.08585947
#3      0     1 0.3246644       0.4682876  0.20704799
#4      1     1 0.3033554       0.4728797  0.22376497
```

Now, manually reproduce these values:

```
  # store the intercept values
intcpts <- coef(summary(m))[3:4]

  # unlikely only
unl <- (1 / (1 + exp(-(intcpts[1] + sum(coef(m) * c(public=0,pared=0) )  ))))
# 0.5960409
  # somewhat likely ((unlikely + somewhat likely) - unlikely)
swl <- (1 / (1 + exp(-(intcpts[2] + sum(coef(m) * c(public=0,pared=0) )  )))) - unl
# 0.3255546
  # very likely (1 - somewhat likely  - unlikely)
vrl <- 1 - swl - unl
# 0.07840448
```

So this all works fine.
However, in the process of figuring this out, I found another page on the UCLA site (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/dae/ologit.htm) which seemed to suggest that one should calculate the values the other way around (very likely, then somewhat, then unlikely - reference category last). As in:

$ P(Y = 2) = \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{-(a_{2}+b_{1}x_{1} + b_{2}x_{2} + b_{3}x_{3})}}\right) $

$ P(Y = 1) = \left(\frac{1}{1 + e^{-(a_{1}+b_{1}x_{1} + b_{2}x_{2} + b_{3}x_{3})}}\right) - P(Y = 2) $

$P(Y = 0) = 1 - P(Y = 1) - P(Y = 2) $

Now I realise this should give the exact same results as the probabilities always add to 1, but I can't seem to get their logic to work in terms of actual R code or manual calculations. I am stuck always starting with unlikely and then moving on up to very likely.

Am I missing something in the logic here? Can anyone suggest a simple calculation method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I get the correct results by removing the minus signs from the exponential...

```
> (P2 <- 1 / (1 + exp(intcpts[2])))
[1] 0.07840448

> (P1 <- 1 / (1 + exp(intcpts[1])) - P2)
[1] 0.3255546

> (P0 <- 1 - P1 - P2)
[1] 0.5960409
```

I streamlined these calculations because in the first row of your table, the values of `public` and `pared` are both zero.

Perhaps SPSS doesn't parameterize the model in the same way? Note in the help page for `polr`, the model is stated as:
$$ 
\mbox{logit}\; P(Y \le k \;|\; x) = \zeta_k - \beta'x 
$$
where $\beta'x = \eta$ is the linear predictor. Note the minus sign there.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still confused how would this work when you **don't** use the case where `coef(m)` are both 0 and don't affect the returned value.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it now. Something like `1 / (1 + exp(-(sum(coef(m) * c(public=1,pared=1)) - intcpts[2])))` should get there for very likely, where public/pared = 1/1

Comment: I think you need to get over those minus signs. More likely it is `1 / (1 + exp(sum(coef(m) * c(public=1,pared=1) + intcpts[2])))`.

Comment: That seems to not give the result I am looking for, i.e. - it gives `0.00213` instead of the `0.2237` it should give.

Comment: Hmmmm. Well, I'm *sure* about the last plus sign because that is what was needed for the $(0,0)$ case.

Comment: Alright, I've played a bit more. I think simpler would be: `1 / (1 + exp(intcpts[2] - sum(coef(m) * c(public=1,pared=1))))`